# Store Select Query output in ms access existing table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using select query for below output. But can't store in table. Since there is restriction in MS access to run update query in select statement.
So please someone can share their idea or existing attributes to resolve this issue.

```
ID  itemno     supplier  ROW_NO UPLOAD_DATE
1   131AF010000CLT  3G60    1   06/17/2020
2   131AF010000CLT  3G60    2   06/14/2019
3   131AF010000CLT  3G60    3   03/22/2019
```

.

```
SELECT itemno, supplier, Upload_Date, 
(Select count(*) 
 FROM Sample_Upload as Dummy 
 where Dummy.itemno=Sample_Upload.itemno 
   and Dummy.supplier=Sample_Upload.supplier 
   and Dummy.UPLOAD_DATE<Sample_Upload.UPLOAD_DATE)+1 AS Seq_No
FROM Sample_Upload
ORDER BY itemno, Supplier, Upload_date, Seq_No;
```

Comment: The restriction Access doesn't allow use of non-updatable query as source for an UPDATE action. An aggregate query is not updatable. Ideally, should not save this calculated data to table, just calculate it when needed.

Comment: But I heard, there is method thru VBA code, we can update the Select query result in another or existing table.

Comment: You can INSERT SELECT records to an existing table or SELECT INTO a new table. VBA can loop through recordset of aggregate query and run UPDATE.

Comment: Please suggest for VBA code!!!